Showing that $\left\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n = +\infty \right\} $ belongs to the terminal $\sigma$-algebra $C_{\infty}$
Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $C_\infty$ denote the terminal $\sigma$-algebra of $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Show that:
$\displaystyle A := \left\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n = +\infty \right\} \in C_\infty$ for $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
I tried using Theorem of Kolmogorov but I wasn't successful.

$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty{S_k\geq n}$
